# Unable to change Google account when logging into Stack Overflow

Tags: support, user-accounts, google

I have a Stack Overflow account associated with a Google account; let's call it 'x@gmail.com'.

I went to sign in to Stack Overflow, and I hit the 'Sign in with Google Account', but I entered the wrong Google account by mistake (let's call it y@gmail.com; I have several). At this point I was prompted to 'Make a new Stack Overflow account with y@gmail.com' and was presented with a <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button.

I hit the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button, and that takes me back to main Stack Overflow page. But when I hit 'Log in' again, hoping that it's entirely forgotten about me, it just takes me back to the same page 'Create a new Stack Overflow account with y@gmail.com'.

OK, so I make another Stack Overflow account with y@gmail.com, hoping that I can just log out and then start again and log in with x@gmail.com. But when I hit 'log in' and select to log in with the Google account, it just signs me in with y@gmail.com again!

How can I log out - and properly log out- so that I can sign in again with my original account x@gmail.com?

Comment: You will need to log out of Google with that account first.

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a bug between the site and Google somewhere. The only workaround I've found is to delete cookies.